# How to add the JSONObject into new JSONArray in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I want to add the JSON Object to new JSON Array ?

For ex:

My current JSON is like below:

```
{
  "name": "Sam",
  "Age": 26,
  "EmpNo": "999999"
}
```

But I want it like below:

```
{
    "details": [
        {
           "name": "Sam",
           "Age": 26,
           "EmpNo": "999999"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone please help me ?

Comment: What have you tried and where is your effort?

Answer (score 1):

In C# has multiple option to do this. One of suggestion refer below:

Create a **Class Object** for your first json.

```
   public class Detail
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    }
```

Then create one more **Class Object** to hold this as a `List`.

```
public class DetailsObject
{
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

after added your Detail object into Details list. just Serialize the Object using `Newtonsoft.Json` Package

```
 var detailsObject = new DetailsObject()
            {
                Details = new List<Detail>(){
                    new Detail(){
                        Name ="Sam",
                        Age =26,
                        EmpNo =999999
                    }
                }
            };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detailsObject , Formatting.Indented);
```